# Query optimisation- Window sort

Tags: database, oracle, query-optimization

I have generated a report using rank().

```
select sa.COUNTRY,
   sa.CITY,
   to_char(sum(r.TOTAL_SERVICE_COST)) as Total_Service_Cost,
   rank() OVER (PARTITION BY sa.COUNTRY
   ORDER BY SUM(r.TOTAL_SERVICE_COST) Desc) as City_Rank_by_country
from ROUTESFACT r,SOURCEAIRPORT_DIM sa
where r.SOURCEAIRPORTID=sa.SOURCE_AIRPORTID
GROUP BY sa.COUNTRY,sa.CITY;
```

And I get the following execution plan.
[image]

As you see window sort and hash group by are not optimised effectively.
What is the best way to optimise this?

Comment: The execution plan looks good to me.  The query includes all the rows from the fact table, and the joins are cheap so an index won't help there.  If the data is grouped and ranked, there has to be a group and sort operation in the plan.  The cost is small so parallelism isn't worth it.  I'm not seeing an obvious problem with this execution plan.  Is there any information you can add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, right your query using proper, explicit `join` syntax.  A neat, properly written query is easier to improve:

```
select sa.COUNTRY, sa.CITY,
       to_char(sum(r.TOTAL_SERVICE_COST)) as Total_Service_Cost,
       rank() OVER (PARTITION BY sa.COUNTRY
                    ORDER BY SUM(r.TOTAL_SERVICE_COST) Desc
                   ) as City_Rank_by_country
from ROUTESFACT r join
     SOURCEAIRPORT_DIM sa
     on r.SOURCEAIRPORTID = sa.SOURCE_AIRPORTID
group by sa.COUNTRY, sa.CITY;
```

I'm not sure how much they will help, but indexes are a good way to start:  `SOURCEAIRPORT_DIM(Country, City, SOURCE_AIRPORTID)` and `ROUTESFACT(SOURCEAIRPORTID, TOTAL_SERVICE_COST)`.

These might help your query.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Creating indexes certainly optimised the query.